# load all the posts with the many tags - Laravel

Tags: laravel, tags, polymorphism, load

I have a polymorphic relationship between post <=> taggables <=> category. Each post has many tags and each category has many tags. How can I load all posts with the tags of the category?

Post:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'categories_posts');
}
```

Category:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'categories_posts');
}
```

Tag:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Category', 'taggable');
}
```

posts can have may categories and many categories can have many posts. But i dont have a table for that.

Comment: plz provide the relationships code

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: what is the relation between category and post ?

Comment: many to many - posts can have many categories and many categories can have many posts. But i dont have a table for that.

Comment: you need to define a pivot table

Comment: If i define a pivot table categories_posts. How do i assign the posts to the right categories?

Answer (score 0):

First define the pivot table for many-to-many relationship between posts and categories table

then you can get categories of post's tags

```
$post = Post::with('tags.categories')->find('x'); 

foreach($post->tags as $tag){
  foreach($tag->categories as $category){
    $category->name;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. Example: The post have the tags (tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6) and the categorie have the tags (tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6) then the post should be displayed in the categorie.